# Simplifying expressions containing derivatives of the assumptions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, calculus-and-analysis

I want to `Simplify` expressions with terms like these:

```
D[f[x,y],x]-D[g[x,y],x]+...
```

but when i use

```
f[x,y]==g[x,y]
```

as assumption *Mathematica* doesn't automatically use the derivative of the assumption.
To simplify the expression I need to manually add

```
D[f[x,y],x]==D[g[x,y],x]
```

to my assumptions.

Is there a way to tell *Mathematica* that with every assumption, it can also use all of the derivatives of the assumption to simplify my expression?